# NSMutableArray lost all object when not focus in nswindow

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, nswindow

In my application, i run a "nstimer" but when i lost focus my nswindow, my array lost all object, my timer still run.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was auto released. Without any code it is difficult to pinpoint the problem

Comment: sorry, I have a mistake, it not run when i clicked on Windows:
timerScan = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(scanThread) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];